# MATLAB - Create a temperature distribution graph

Tags: arrays, matlab, graph, mask, temperature

I have a meshgrid mask array that has the temperature distribution along the geometry (x,y,t). I need to make a graph of the temperature change along, let's say, y = 10.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you represent your data in 3D meshgrid while you work on 2D meshgrid, assuming `t` in `(x, y, t)` stands for temperature. If you create a 2D meshgrid and calculate t, then it is easy to plot it, e.g:

```
 x = 1:20;
 y = 1:20;
 [X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
 t = X.^2 + Y.^2; % Add your t equation here using your meshgrid X and Y
 figure;plot(x, t(10,x));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and you're right t is temperature, apologies. This has brought me a step closer, however it's just a straight line, it doesn't mimic the temperature distribution that I can see visually in my mask array i.e. the temperature goes up from 40 C to 52 C along y = 10mm, this isn't represented in the graph - do you know why?

Comment: I edit the code a bit, you can check again. Sorry, I cannot help if you do not show sample code and sample outputs etc. It is just a 'geusswork' now